# Running a desktop on docker containers

Tags: linux, docker, container

Is it possible to run x11 server inside docker containers running on headless server. So that I could use gui applications inside them.
What I mean by that is I have a single container which is my main desktop and others which are used to run software as firefox or chrome. Much like qubes os but without spinning up a whole new vm.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to run a headless VNC server inside a Docker container.

You may download a ready-made one from
[consol/ubuntu-xfce-vnc](https://hub.docker.com/r/consol/ubuntu-xfce-vnc/),
described as:

> Ubuntu container with "headless" VNC session, Xfce4 UI and preinstalled Firefox and Chrome browser

For detailed instructions on how to build such a container, see for example
[View a Docker container’s display using VNC Viewer](https://qxf2.com/blog/view-docker-container-display-using-vnc-viewer/) from September, 2017.
However, due to the rapid development of Docker this might not stay correct
forever.